# Determinant of (A²+B²).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ and $B$ be distinct matrices. Knowing that $A^3=B^3$ and $A^2B=B^2A$, what's the value of $\det(A^2+B^2)$?

From the comment.
I end up finding that $\det(A^2+B^2)=\det(A)\det(A+B)$. I dont know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: expand a certain polynomial.

Comment: The usual questions: 1. What did you try? 2. Where are you having trouble in what you tried?

Comment: @MasB I end up finding that Det(A²+B²)=Det(A)Det(A+B). I dont know how to proceed.

Comment: You have information about $A^3,B^3, A^2B$ and $B^2A$. Do you know any polynomials that contain all of those terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly I didn't understand the hints that were in the comments.
This is how one can reason.
Since.
$$
(A^2+B^2)A=A^3+B^2A=B^3+A^2B=(B^2+A^2)B,
$$
then $(A^2+B^2)A=(A^2+B^2)B$. If $\det(A^2+B^2)\neq0$, then the matrix $A^2+B^2$ is invertible and hence $A=B$.
Since by the condition $A\neq B$, we have $\det(A^2+B^2)=0$.

Comment: Now I undestand! Thank you!